# How i can do simple refresh on a gradle project using cmd or gitbash

Tags: gradle, cmd, git-bash, spring-tool-suite

My project structure consist of both front-end(Angular) and back-end(Spring MVC) code. Whenever i do any front end changes normally i do npm run build from git-bash/cmd, after that i have to manually open STS, right click on project and do a normal refresh or f5(note: not gradle refresh), by this new bundle which is generated (by npm run build) will get loaded into project and published to tomcat server.

My queries: 
1. I want to do a normal refresh (not gradle refresh) for my project from cmd/gitbash.
2. I want the club two command in into a single command, it is possible ? like doing the front-end code build and then normal refresh to project.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure, but I think the 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' preference is the answer to your question:

[image]